# Dilate and erode SVG shapes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, geometry

EDIT:

I finally found a way to erode and dilate polygons (offsetting) so that new geometry is created using Clipper library:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/

Live demo of Javascript Clipper:
http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/5.0.2.1/main_demo.html

The Clipper can only handle polygons or multi-polygons (eg. polygons with holes), so for it to work with other graphical objects of SVG format, they have to be converted to straight lines. At least paths are rather easy to convert to lines using `path.getTotalLength()` and `path.getPointAtLength()` (http://whaticode.com/2012/02/01/converting-svg-paths-to-polygons/).

The other possibility is use this like technique (that does not create new geometry):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12723835/1691517

---

Is there any way to erode and dilate shapes in SVG via Javascript?

I have the following SVG example:
http://jsfiddle.net/timo2012/2S4Kt/1/

There are three shapes, blue is original, green is eroded (thinned) and red is dilated (bolded). They are made in Illustrator.

I have tested erode and dilate filters, but the effect is not so good:
https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/examples/feMorphology.svg

After few hours searching over internet, I have found only examples about bitmap image eroding and dilating, but nothing about vector shapes.

I have succeeded in dilating and eroding SVG polygons using Shapely ( http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html ) in Python by sending path points via Ajax call to PHP script which makes system() call to Python script, but this method is slow and requires server to do the work that could be done client side.

This is my code for dilating and eroding in Python (as you see it is quite short):

```
#!/usr/bin/python26

from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon

import sys

if len(sys.argv)>2:
  inset=eval(sys.argv[1])
  coords=eval(sys.argv[2])
else:
  sys.exit()

bowtie = Polygon(coords)
clean = bowtie.buffer(inset)
clean = clean.simplify(1, preserve_topology=False)
if clean.length>0:
  if clean.geom_type=="MultiPolygon":
    for n in range(0, len(clean)):
      print list(clean[n].exterior.coords)
      #print "\n"
  elif clean.geom_type=="Polygon":
    print list(clean.exterior.coords)
```

Also find this document, which tries to define dilate and erode in mathematical terms:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology

There is a sentence "The basic idea in binary morphology is to probe an image with a simple, pre-defined shape, drawing conclusions on how this shape fits or misses the shapes in the image. This simple "probe" is called structuring element, and is itself a binary image (i.e., a subset of the space or grid)."

I assume that this method could be used in morphing vector shapes, but how...

EDIT: One comment in a reply raised a possible issue of using filters instead of creating new geometry: if someone wants to add drag handles to polygon points, then drag handles may seem to be in wrong place. This can be acceptable, because then the impression is that the original path data is untouched, which is actually the case in filters, but - after further testing - it proved that the quality is a bigger problem. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12705125/1691517) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12718568/1691517) SVG filter uses pixel representation of vector graphic object instead of path data itself, which leads to [not so good looking results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12702955/1691517).

EDIT2: POSSIBLE WORKAROUND: One of the answers in this page led me to use variable-width strokes and mask to achieve a good looking workaround to this issue. I made a few tests and get implemented [an Adobe Illustrator -like Offset Path Effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12723835/1691517).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort of get what you seem to be after by stroking with different stroke-widths in combination with `clip-path` or `mask`. Here's an [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/presentations/svgopen2012/presentation/), some explanations of how it's constructed see [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/presentations/svgopen2012/presentation/index.html#/0/2) and [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/presentations/svgopen2012/presentation/index.html#/0/2) (arrow up or down to see some other slides on that example).

It doesn't give you new geometry though, just something that might look like new geometry.

Comment: Thanks for this! I checked those, but if polygon control points have to be draggable, then this technique is not helpful, am I right?

Comment: Like I wrote you don't get any new geometry from this, so if that's what you need then this might not help. You could still have drag handles on the original path, which could affect the other thinned/bolded paths.

Comment: Ok. Seems that I'm seeking new geometry. But a little surprise is that such basic geometric functions cannot be find readymade tens with googling around. The same situation is with boolean functions. Where are all the mathematicians? They all should be coding these functions! SVG and Javascript matters!

Comment: I'm trying to your proposal in reality to achieve the effect of Offset Path in Illustrator. Can a stroke used to cut something, or only the fill of shape? Or what do you mean with "different stroke-widths in combination with clip-path or mask"?

Comment: Offsetting path positive (Dilate) is not a big problem, because we can define the border color to the same as fill color. Offset negative (Erode) is a bigger problem. Can it be simply achieved by making border color transparent?

Comment: Finally got it (path based erode and dilate) to work by thinking a little your sentence "different stroke-widths in combination with ... mask". Thanks a lot! No need for new geometry, the original path is enough and it's now similar to Illustrator's Offset Path.

Comment: I should accept this as a right answer, because your instructions helped me to find a good workaround. I analyzed my question once more and ended up with a presumption that I asked a javascript based solution to dilate/erode shapes by modifying original path data instead of modifying it server side in Python. So I'm not sure if I should accept this as a right answer or not. For now I clicked +1 to show that this answer was useful and helpful.

Comment: I accept this as a right answer, because this idea is the most simple and efficient. The scripting way which produces new geometry should take into account various shapes (rectangles, ellipses, paths) and the calculation via Javascript would be slow. The new geometry can be also achieved by rasterizing shape, making erosion and then vectorizing again, but too slow.

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually tested SVG's native filters? This looks close enough:

```
<svg width="612" height="792" viewBox="0 0 612 792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <defs>
    <filter id="erode">
      <feMorphology operator="erode" in="SourceGraphic" radius="12" />
    </filter>
    <filter id="dilate">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceGraphic" radius="8" />
    </filter>
      <path id="original_path" d="M193.193,85c23.44,0.647,45.161,0.774,62,12c1.596,1.064,12,11.505,12,13
    c0,2.941,8.191,5.669,3,12c-3.088,3.767-6.01-0.758-11-1c-19.56-0.948-33.241,12.296-33,34c0.163,14.698,8.114,24.492,4,41
    c-1.408,5.649-6.571,15.857-10,21c-2.484,3.726-7.898,10.784-12,13c-4.115-11.677,2.686-27.29-6-35c-6.693-5.942-20.021-4.051-26,1
    c-13.573,11.466-11.885,41.492-7,58c-5.8,1.772-18.938,7.685-23,12c-6.752-10.805-15.333-17.333-24-26c-3.307-3.307-9.371-12-15-12
    c-16.772,0-13.963-15.741-13-28c1.283-16.324,1.727-28.24,4-42c1.276-7.72,8-16.411,8-23c0-7.416,15.945-29,23-29
    c4.507,0,17.678-8.701,24-11C164.853,90.76,178.27,88.546,193.193,85"/>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#original_path" fill="#f00" filter="url(#dilate)"></use>    
  <use xlink:href="#original_path" fill="blue"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#original_path" fill="#1CFF00" filter="url(#erode)"></use>    
</svg>
```

There is some clipping going on the `dilate` filter that can't seem to be resolved by increasing the filter region, but other than that it's pretty close to your illustrator rendering. Sure beats rendering server-side.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Qv5v/

Comment: Thank you for the effort! The filter is not very bad, but still not suitable in all situations. What if we add drag handles to polygon points, how filter based solution fits to it?

Comment: If that is your use case then you should state it in your question.

Comment: Added this. I nearly forgot that svg can be used also as a plain image without interactivity :) Thanks for reminder!

Comment: The above filter solution in http://jsfiddle.net/5Qv5v/ doesn't seem to work in iPhone4 Safari. Only green path is visible. By contract, the geometry based solution in http://jsfiddle.net/timo2012/2S4Kt/1/ works in that platform.

Comment: It is well known that iOS < 6 doesn't support SVG Filters http://caniuse.com/svg-filters and please don't pile up requirements on your questions.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I transferred "the drag handles" issue to the end of the question to make it clear that it was not explicated when question was created. Happy now?

Comment: I meant that as general advice for using StackOverflow: you will get better answers when you state upfront your use case and what browsers you intend to support. Otherwise you deprecate answers as you are adding new requirements.

Comment: May be somebody removes this comment as offtopic, but really enjoyed your kerning game in: http://type.method.ac/ !