# Offsetting polygons in Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, geometry, script#

EDIT5: Finally got Angus Johnson's Clipper library implemented in Javascript and selected Sourceforge for host.

LIVE DEMO: http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/6.1.1.1/main_demo.html

Download source:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/

Wikipage with step-by-step tutorial:
https://sourceforge.net/p/jsclipper/wiki/Home%206/

Presentation of Demo Program including tens of sample polygons:
https://sourceforge.net/p/jsclipper/wiki/Main_Demo%206/

I hope this helps anyone who needs polyline and polygon clipping library with offsetting features.

---

EDIT4: The one possibility is to convert pascal to javascript using
http://p2js.gelicon.biz/en/ . Not succeeded yet. `p2js.exe clipper.pas` gives Fatal error "Can't find unit system used by clipper".

---

EDIT: I found [script#](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/178fe024-29f2-467c-a1da-284fedd1ac19) ([Github](https://github.com/nikhilk/ScriptSharp)), which seems to be able to convert C# to Javascript. Clipper lib is available in C#, so would it be possible to make C#->JS conversion using Script# and how?

EDIT3: Got not converted with script#, but there is also Emscripten, but 4000 cpp lines converted to 300 000 Javascript lines, so not an option. Manual conversion seems to be a king.

---

EDIT2: I made [an example](http://jsbin.com/izafix/2/), which shows the problem. Use arrow left and right to apply offset. In certain distance it works ok, but then something goes wrong. The yellow stroked polygon is so called raw offset polygon, and AFAIK Clipper lib provides a way to take care of removing unneeded parts of raw offset polygon.

---

There is a Clipper library by Angus Johnson for offsetting polygons.

I'd need this functionality in Javascript for offsetting SVG polygons.

**Has someone made a Javascript port of it?**

If not, I'd appreciate some guidelines eg. the following:
- how enormous task it would be?
- which one to choose for source (Delphi, C#, C++)?
- is everything in lib needed for offsetting?

The Clipper library produces the following results which are just the desired functionality:

[image: Offset Polygons, polygons, delta, jointype, miterlimit, jtSquare jtRound jtMiter]

Some links:
- [Files in Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/polyclipping/files/)
- [Clipper Documentation](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper/documentation/Docs/Units/ClipperLib/Functions/OffsetPolygons.htm)
- [One Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7947389/1691517)
- [Offsetting algorithm](http://www.me.berkeley.edu/~mcmains/pubs/DAC05OffsetPolygon.pdf)

Comment: Didn't you solve this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723832/how-can-i-implement-offset-path-effect-in-svg-without-using-javascript-or-dilate/12723835#12723835

Comment: Sort of, but I'd appreciate simple new geometry (polygon) instead of complex structures of masks or adjacent duplicate objects, which may not work in every platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have succeded in porting clipper to JS, and after a while, after thorough testing going to release it. Seems that all the functionality could have been ported.

One caveat, 128bit support is reduced to 106bit.

One of the pros is to reach large space of browsers and possibility to use svg, vml, html5 canvas as graphics interface.

Any ideas, Which host would be easiest to publish, with demo possibility?

---

EDIT:

Finally got Angus Johnson's Clipper library implemented in Javascript and selected Sourceforge for host.

LIVE DEMO:
http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/6.1.1.1/main_demo.html

Downloads:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/

Wikipage with step-by-step tutorial:
https://sourceforge.net/p/jsclipper/wiki/Home%206/

Presentation of Demo Program including tens of sample polygons:
https://sourceforge.net/p/jsclipper/wiki/Main_Demo%206/

I hope this helps anyone who needs polyline and polygon clipping library with offsetting features.

Answer (score 3):

```
    function offsetPoints(pts, offset) {
        let newPoints = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < pts.length; j++) {
            let i = (j - 1);
            if (i < 0) i += pts.length;
            let k = (j + 1) % pts.length;

            let v1 = [pts[j].x - pts[i].x, pts[j].y - pts[i].y];
            let mag1 = Math.sqrt(v1[0] * v1[0] + v1[1] * v1[1])
            v1 = [v1[0] / mag1, v1[1] / mag1]
            v1 = [v1[0] * offset, v1[1] * offset]
            let n1 = [-v1[1], v1[0]];
            let x1 = pts[i].x + n1[0];
            let y1 = pts[i].y + n1[1];
            let x2 = pts[j].x + n1[0];
            let y2 = pts[j].y + n1[1];

            let v2 = [pts[k].x - pts[j].x, pts[k].y - pts[j].y];
            let mag2 = Math.sqrt(v2[0] * v2[0] + v2[1] * v2[1])
            v2 = [v2[0] / mag2, v2[1] / mag2]
            v2 = [v2[0] * offset, v2[1] * offset]
            let n2 = [-v2[1], v2[0]];
            let x3 = pts[j].x + n2[0];
            let y3 = pts[j].y + n2[1];
            let x4 = pts[k].x + n2[0];
            let y4 = pts[k].y + n2[1];

            let den = ((y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1));
            let ua = ((x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3)) / den;
            let x = x1 + ua * (x2 - x1);
            let y = y1 + ua * (y2 - y1);

            newPoints.push({ x, y });
        }

        return newPoints;
    }
```

Comment: Seems like it contains some error. Can you show how it works in an example?

Answer (score 2):

There are no simple solutions when it comes to polygon inflating. If you have a concave polygon, sooner or later it will break into several smaller polygons if you decrease the offset enough. So I would suggest using an existing, proven, algorithm (Clipper should be a good one).

On your question about porting C# to JS, I would say it's certainly possible, but the question is how much time it would take and whether the auto-porting tools will be of any use. Judging from [this discussion](http://sourceforge.net/p/polyclipping/discussion/1148419/thread/a3da69a1), I doubt it:

> I took a quick stab at using ScriptSharp to translate the C# code to
> Javascript, but there are too many incompatible structures to use that
> and I couldn't get it to output a javascript file. Trying to implement
> the Vatti clipping algorithm in Javascript seems to be the next step.
>
> ...
>
> And yes, it won't help you using all sorts of automatics conversion
> tools.The clipper has data structures like Int64 or Int128 which are
> non existent in JS or AS .I just removed them altogether .Int32 should
> be enough for most cases unless you work on smth related to geography
> or huge maps .

The ActionScript port one of the users there mentions is no longer available, unfortunately.

Comment: This is at least available: https://github.com/ChrisDenham/PolygonClipper.AS3. You are right that automatic conversion is not an option. Using Emscripten 4000 cpp lines converted to 300 000 JS lines. I don't even tested if it works...

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working example of [Angus Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359538/angus-johnson) code which is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7947389/6908282). It uses the [Javascript Clipper](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/) which is a port of Angus's code.

This is copied from [here](https://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/6.4.2.2/index.html?p=sources_as_text/basic_demo_offset_svg.txt) as a reference in case the website url changes since its old.

```js
// https://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/6.4.2.2/index.html?p=sources_as_text/basic_demo_offset_svg.txt
function draw() {
    var svg, cont = document.getElementById('svgcontainer'), i, ii, j;
    var paths = [[{ X: 30, Y: 30 }, { X: 130, Y: 30 }, { X: 130, Y: 130 }, { X: 30, Y: 130 }],
    [{ X: 60, Y: 60 }, { X: 60, Y: 100 }, { X: 100, Y: 100 }, { X: 100, Y: 60 }]];
    var scale = 100;
    ClipperLib.JS.ScaleUpPaths(paths, scale);
    var joinTypes = [ClipperLib.JoinType.jtSquare, ClipperLib.JoinType.jtRound, ClipperLib.JoinType.jtMiter];
    var endType = ClipperLib.EndType.etClosedPolygon;

    var joinTypesTexts = ["Square", "Round", "Miter"];
    var deltas = [-10, 0, 10];

    var co = new ClipperLib.ClipperOffset(); // constructor
    var offsetted_paths = new ClipperLib.Paths(); // empty solution

    for (i = 0; i < joinTypes.length; i++) {
        for (ii = 0; ii < deltas.length; ii++) {
            co.Clear();
            co.AddPaths(paths, joinTypes[i], endType);
            co.MiterLimit = 2;
            co.ArcTolerance = 0.25;

            co.Execute(offsetted_paths, deltas[ii] * scale);
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(offsetted_paths));

            svg = `<svg id="${i.toString() + ii.toString()}" style="margin-top:10px;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:#dddddd" width="160" height="160">`;
            svg += '<path stroke="black" fill="yellow" stroke-width="2" d="' + paths2string(offsetted_paths, scale) + '"/>';
            svg += '</svg>';
            cont.innerHTML += svg;
        }
        cont.innerHTML += "<br>" + joinTypesTexts[i] + " " + deltas[0] + ", ";
        cont.innerHTML += joinTypesTexts[i] + " " + deltas[1] + ", ";
        cont.innerHTML += joinTypesTexts[i] + " " + deltas[2] + "<hr>";
    }
}

// Converts Paths to SVG path string
// and scales down the coordinates
function paths2string(paths, scale) {
    var svgpath = "", i, j;
    if (!scale) scale = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < paths[i].length; j++) {
            if (!j) svgpath += "M";
            else svgpath += "L";
            svgpath += (paths[i][j].X / scale) + ", " + (paths[i][j].Y / scale);
        }
        svgpath += "Z";
    }
    if (svgpath == "") svgpath = "M0,0";
    return svgpath;
}
```

```css
h3 {
  margin-bottom: 2px
}

body,
th,
td,
input,
legend,
fieldset,
p,
b,
button,
select,
textarea {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!-- ref: https://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/6.4.2.2/index.html?p=sources_as_text/basic_demo_offset_svg.txt -->

<html>

<head>
  <title>Javascript Clipper Library / Offsetting polygons / SVG example</title>
  <!-- <script src="clipper.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipper-lib@6.4.2/clipper.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload="draw()">
  <h2>Javascript Clipper Library / Offsetting polygons / SVG example</h2>
  This page shows an example of offsetting polygons and drawing them using SVG.
  <div id="svgcontainer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: these are some npm libraries I found for this : 1 - [clipper-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipper-lib), 2- [js-clipper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-clipper)

Comment: typescript port - https://github.com/ghent360/clipper

Comment: another typescript package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/offset-polygon. But this is not reliable

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-clipper - this package has a typed definition - but its only updated to v5.0.2 of Angus code. So it doesn't have offset

Comment: ⭐ The simplest typescript supported npm package that worked for me was [js-angusj-clipper](https://github.com/xaviergonz/js-angusj-clipper/issues/3#issuecomment-1980806036)

Answer (score 0):

The Clipper approach by Angus Johnson is the best one, but it was difficult for me to find a npm package which supports typescripts. After much search I found
[js-angusj-clipper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-angusj-clipper).

Below is an example code that worked for me

```js
async angusClipper() {

    // create an instance of the library (usually only do this once in your app)
    const clipper = await clipperLib.loadNativeClipperLibInstanceAsync(
        // let it autodetect which one to use, but also available WasmOnly and AsmJsOnly
        clipperLib.NativeClipperLibRequestedFormat.WasmWithAsmJsFallback
    );

    const offsetResult = clipper.offsetToPaths({
        // ref: https://github.com/xaviergonz/js-angusj-clipper/issues/3
        delta: -50,
        offsetInputs: [{
            data: [
                { x: 87, y: 306 },
                { x: 553, y: 294 },
                { x: 421, y: 8 },
                { x: 285, y: 291 },
                { x: 110, y: 13 },
            ],
            joinType: clipperLib.JoinType.Square,
            endType: clipperLib.EndType.ClosedPolygon
        }]
    })

    console.log({ offsetResult })
}
```