# Selecting the unused area of a polygon as a new polygon in Google Maps API v.3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geometry, polygons

I'm trying to calculate and select the remaining area of a polygon when another polygon is placed inside it. I have an initial outer polygon. I then add a smaller polygon inside it which is up against the edge, sharing one or more sides with the outer polygon. I'm trying to get a new polygon path for the remaining unused area of the outer polygon.

As the 2 polygons share a boundary I'm looking to get a single polygon path for the new polygon rather than a complex polygon made up of an outer path and a hole/island.

Google Maps API Geometry library does have a method for detecting if a point is near the edge of a polygon - [google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly). I think that this is the way forward. I can get these points and push them into new arrays or use their indices. I just can't figure out how to use them to get to the remaining area.

Any help would be welcome whether it's Google Maps specific or just more general geometry theory.

Comment: Look at the [JSTS library](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jsts)

Comment: This is a [Boolean operation on polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons).  The [JavaScript Clipper Library](http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/6.1.1.1/main_demo.html) described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248896/offsetting-polygons-in-javascript) might help you here also.