# Create new polygon inside existing polygon with uniform offset/margin in Google Maps API v.3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geometry, margin, offset, polygons

I have a polygon and want to create a new polygon inside it which is spaced exactly 5 metres from the edge all around.

My thinking is to calculate the [centroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid), then get each point of the outer polygon and move it 5 metres towards the centroid.

Using the [google.maps.geometry.spherical](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) functions I should be able to computeHeading() to get the direction towards the centroid, then computeOffset() using the distance and the heading (direction).

This would move all of the vertices in by 5 metres. Would this mean that all my lines would automatically be spaced at 5 metres apart or would it depend on angles? I can do the JavaScript, not sure about the geometry. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Possibly the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248896/offsetting-polygons-in-javascript

Comment: You need to offset each edge of the polygon along its own normal vector, not towards the centroid, then trim or extend the corners to miter the polygon.  It's nontrivial, and the library mentioned here may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248896/offsetting-polygons-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks @dbc. It's a lot more complicated than I had imagined, which is very useful to know in itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that very complicated which requiers large libraries. All you need to do is to calculate new polygon points along the mid-angle between the adjacent two edges. Here is a simple python function which will do it:

```
def shrinkPoly(poly, dd):
     spoly = []

     for i in range(len(poly)):

          ip1 = i+1
          if ip1 >= len(poly): ip1 = 0
          
          vm = norm(poly[i-1] - poly[i])
          vp = norm(poly[ip1] - poly[i])
          aa = acos(dot(vm, vp))
          crsmp = cross(vm,vp)[2]
          vo = poly[i] - sign(crsmp) * norm((vm+vp))*dd/sin(aa/2)
          spoly.append(vo)

     return spoly
```

dd is the distance you want as the margin between your original polygon and the new polygon edges.

Here you have to notice two things:

1.) sign(crsmp) handles the edge concavity at a given polygon point. So you either add or subtract margin amount depending on whether the polygon is convex or concave at that specific point.

2.) Division by sin(aa/2) calculates the correct distance form old polygon point to new point for a given margin for edges.