# Create An SVG Path By A Fixed, Perpendicular Distance, With Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

[image]

I have an SVG path like the blue one above. How can I create a Path like the black one, that is inset by a fixed distance (red) from every side of the black Path?
I try to scale the path element but that's not in a same distance with every line

Comment: It's very hard to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723832/how-can-i-implement-offset-path-effect-in-svg-without-using-javascript-or-dilate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this thread help you ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12723835/6852641

There are some nice examples such as http://jsfiddle.net/BbYV6/ which uses masks and stroke width to create an "offset path" effect

```
<mask id="myMask" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
  <use xlink:href="#text" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="40"/>
</mask>
```

Comment: yes it's working but I need exact coordination of that path