# How to find data for an offset path around an SVG <path> element

Tags: html, svg, vector

Given a path data string for an svg `<path>` element, I need a way to calculate new data for a path that surrounds the original path at a specified offset.

**For example:** let's take a star SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <path d="M 259.216,29.942 330.27,173.919 489.16,197.007 374.185,309.08 401.33,467.31 259.216,392.612 117.104,467.31 144.25,309.08 29.274,197.007 188.165,173.919 z"/>
</svg>
```

Which renders like so:

[image: star]

I need to calculate the data for a path that would surround the star at a given distance (a.k.a. "offset").

[image: star outlined]

---

**So, My question is:** If I have a desired offset, how can I take the path data for the inner (solid) star, and calculate path data for the outer (outline) star?

It may seem as though I should just scale up the star shape and use that. But the outline is, in fact, a different shape with different proportions. This becomes more apparent with larger offsets and more complex shapes.

It seems like the solution would only require some (heavy) math, so the solution should theoretically be language-agnostic. But maybe I'm missing something... My application's backend runs on **PHP** so I would prefer that.

I feel like this must have been solved somewhere but I can't seem to find a library that can do this kind of operation. I looked at D3.js and the Imagick PHP class but neither seemed to have what is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a js library that you can use: [flatten-js](https://github.com/alexbol99/flatten-js)(to load and manipulate polygon data) with [polygon-offset](https://github.com/alexbol99/flatten-offset) library which does exactly what you are looking for.
To convert the SVG path data to points you can use https://github.com/nornagon/flatten-svg

Something similar can be simply achieved with Dilate filter in SVG, but that will expand the raster data, instead of creating another path data.

Or, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12723835/2229899) is an amazing answer that explains how to do this inside the SVG file by experimenting with stroke-width, but it would require some manual work.

Comment: Thanks, @Palash_Bansal. I need to create a Polygon from existing SVG path data. But I don't see a way to do this with flatten-js. It seems you can only create a polygon from the libraries methods of Segment, Point, etc...

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to do this is scaling a copy of the star around it's center. In this case the copy is an use element

```css
use {
      transform-origin: center;
      transform: scale(1.13);
    }
    
 svg{width:90vh}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 520 512">
  <use xlink:href="#star" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" />

  <path id="star" d="M 259.216,29.942 330.27,173.919 489.16,197.007 374.185,309.08 401.33,467.31 259.216,392.612 117.104,467.31 144.25,309.08 29.274,197.007 188.165,173.919 z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: What I need is the actual path data for that red outline. Not only to display it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this efficiently by manually calculating the appropriate transformation matrix (translate the center to 0,0; scale by X%; reverse the initial translation) - but if you want to avoid matrices, you can brute force it with algebra & the cartesian distance formula:

1. Calculate the center of the polygon - x0, y0
2. Take any polygon end point - x1, y1
3. The line defined by x0, y0 <-> x1, y1 is of the form y= nx + a

   - since you have the two coordinates you can find n and a by substitution
4. If the new polygon point (x2, y2) is B distance away from x1,y1 (where B is equal to e.g. 120% of the SQRT ((x1-x0)^2 + (y1-y0)^2) [cartesian distance formula] then you know that
   B = SQRT ((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2) [The cartesian distance formula again]
   AND that y2 = nx2 + a (it has to be on the line)

Solve by substitution - which will give you two possible points for x2, y2 - one of which will lie on the segment between x0,y0 and x1, y1 - which you can test calculating whether x2,y2 is closer to x0, y0 than x1, y1. The other point is the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to handle any path. Including those with bézier curves. Correct?

- Lines are relatively simple.  Michael has offered some help there.
- Arcs are more complicated.  You will likely need to find the centre of the circle corresponding to the arc. The SVG spec can help you there. It includes a [section on converting to "centre parameterization"](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#implnote-ArcConversionEndpointToCenter).
- Béziers are the most complicated. There is no mathematical formula that you can feed a bézier in and get an offset bézier out.  However you can use successive approximation to get as close as you like.  This [article on the Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465782/control-points-of-offset-bezier-curve) should be useful to you.

  If you want agood primer on the math around bézier curves. I highly recommend [this video from Freya Holmér](https://youtu.be/aVwxzDHniEw). It includes a section on how to find the [tangent and normal](https://youtu.be/aVwxzDHniEw?t=448) to the curve. You could use that to generate a set of line segments that are offset from the curve.  You might find that simpler than the Tiller and Hanson algorithm mentioned above.